# Microsoft Media Foundation in Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, c++-cli, windows-server-2008-r2, ms-media-foundation

We use Microsoft Media Foundation in our app (for app we use C# + C++/CLI) which should run on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2. App works on Win 8 but when we run it on MS Server 2008 R2 machine it crashes with FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. In windows logs we find such error:

> Faulting application name: MOF.Video.Example.exe, version: 1.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x5303b258 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e21213c Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000000cacd Faulting process id: 0xee8 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cf2ce85eee5491 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MOF\MOF.Video.Example.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   9d972c94-98db-11e3-91f3-90e6bac09d51

OS: MS Server 2008 R2 x64

App: x64

Comment: I suppose you need to use [`sxstrace`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875651.aspx) to get more details as for what is exactly missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the Desktop Experience to the server:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772567.aspx
Otherwise, you may be attempting to utilize a codec which is not installed.

Comment: We've already added Desktop Experience and our app crashes on the start, so I don't think it is problem with codec

Comment: Then you may want to run dependency walker to see what is missing (depends.exe):  http://www.dependencywalker.com/     Note the screenshot at the bottom.